# Can OPENCV access a analog camera using a video capture device

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, video-capture

I have been trying to access my analog camera via a EasyCap video capture device. Any code I try only picks the usb webcam or internal webcam. I guess that since video capture device is a video controller, opencv doesnt recognize it as a imaging device.

Can anyone conform if you cannot access analog cameras with opencv via a video capture device.

If so, then what other method can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i struggled with the same problem (in my case within python instead of C++, although I am certain it will be the same root cause) and hope it helps!

[the original thread + ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146205/grab-frame-ntsctousb-dongle-opencv2-python-wrapper/22183737#22183737)

also [relevant XKCD](https://xkcd.com/979/)

Comment: can you please let me know whether OpenCV can access CCTV Cameras?

Answer (score 1):

Even for digital devices, OpenCV isn't good at reading them, it is good at *processing* them. The library has supply for generic webcams, of course; however it does not supply most of the commercial or industrial cameras.

In short, to decode, you should try using *"video for linux"* or *"video for windows"* libraries; or the *device SDK* itself. Since you are using a video2usb converter, you shouldn't have any problem accessing the analog camera through these software.