# Is there an Interactive Data Language (IDL) procedure for accessing a video/camera source?

Tags: video-capture, idl-programming-language

I have considered that one might use an external library somehow (e.g.. [OPENCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833297/can-opencv-access-a-analog-camera-using-a-video-capture-device)), such as via CALL_EXTERNAL, MAKEDLL or LINKIMAGE, but I wonder if there is a built-in IDL procedure for video/camera access. I did not find such a procedure in the IDL documentation, but perhaps someone is aware of such a procedure having been provided by an IDL community member.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing built into IDL for doing this. However, you have a couple of options. Like you suggested, you could write a simple DLM using make_dll. Or, if you wait until IDL 8.5, you could use the new Python bridge to call Python routines from within IDL to access a video camera. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, @Chris, for the heads up about IDL 8.5. I'm still on 8.3, as it has been adequately serving the purposes of my prototyping and experimentation... but I will keep an eye out for 8.5, to see what compelling features it offers.

Answer (score 1):

Also check out David Grier's [OpenCV wrappers](https://github.com/davidgrier/idlvideo).